# Flash: simultaneously changing numbers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do I create a simultaneously changing number in flash?
Something along the lines of milliseconds on a stopwatch, like how they change repeditively.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to change the number each frame.  To do this, you can use the Enter Frame event.  Here is an example.

```
var frameCount:int = 0;

// Add an event listener that will fire on each ENTER_FRAME event.
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, OnEnterFrame);

//This function will get called after each frame
function OnEnterFrame(e:Event):void{
    frameCount++;
    trace(frameCount);
}
```

This example will trace the frameCount once per frame (several times a second).  If you wanted to instead keep track of time, you would need to do 2 things.

1. Declare a variable for when the timer starts, and set it to the current time, which can be done like this:

   var startTime:Number = (new Date()).time;
2. Inside the OnEnterFrame function, grab the new time using the same (new Date()).time method, and subtract the start time from it.  This will give you the diference in milliseconds between when the timer started, and what the current time is.

Events are a big part of AS3, here is a [tutorial](http://tutorials101.blogspot.com/2010/11/as3-event-listener-introduction.html) if you want to learn more.  Hope this helped!

Comment: is there any way to have it change multiple times in a frame?
I would imagine that changing once every frame would be fairly slow.
the use of the numbers wont last that many frames which is why i need them to change kind of rapidly.

Comment: but I don't want the whole movie to be that fast, just the numbers.

Comment: If you only need the time since you started, then all you have to do is set startTime when you want the timer to start, then anywhere else in your code you can do (new Date()).time - startTime; to get the exact time since startTime was set.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: not really,
I dont need the numbers to display any specific time, I just need the "image" of fast changing numbers.  I am planning on having a series of these in a line, sort of like the matrix (how the numbers change repeatedly).  I want them to basically generate the numbers 0-9 repetitively, until I have them fade out.

Comment: I see.  EnterFrame would be perfect for this. You won't need to update the numbers more than once per frame because the user wouldn't see the updates anyways.  Modifying the example above, instead of trace(frameCount); you could do myTextField.text = (frameCount % 10).toString();  Assuming you link to myTextField correctly, this would cause the text field to display 1,2,3,4,etc... very quickly.  The % operator will make sure that we only display a single digit at a time.

Answer (score 1):

read through this, it will give you all the info you need: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3timer/

but essentially you just need something like this

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10,0);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
  trace("10 ms passed");
}
```

the timer is not precise (so you will get +/- a few milliseconds here or there depending on the load, so if you want to use it to display time, use getTimer() http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html

---

millisecond precision would be pretty hard to create this way, and there is no point in updating the timer more often than the frame-rate, as the user can't see the result. (unless there's you're doing more than displaying the time)

but you could have your code look something like this

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10,0);
var startTime:int = -getTimer();
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
myTimer.start();

function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void{
  someTextfield.text = ("ms passed: " + getTimer()+startTime );
}
```

which would show you on `someTextfield` the number of ms passed;

Comment: Just so I understand that,  the code above would have a 10ms timer and If I used the getTimer  it would display a 10ms timer in the movie?  If I set it for (9,10)  would it display a 9ms timer 10 times? (which is basically EXACTLY what I need)

Comment: but then again, I dont want to display something like 00:09 if you know what I mean.. And plus I need to be able to change what it looks like.   What if I had like a number variable that increased each ms, but only going to 9?

I apologize if i'm all over with this, I'm really new to flash.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this for a matrix like effect, you'll probably be better off creating a movieclip. There is no point to doing extra calculations, and having a bunch of event listeners updating a text field above the framerate is overkill.

Add a vertical blur filter on the numbers (or overlay another number with a lowered opacity) and have them skip numbers. That will make it look like it's being updated quickly, because just changing the numbers won't have that effect.